# what is the alternative for "while" / "for" loops

Tags: c++, loops

I have got a homework where I should do some action again and again till I write "stop" in console, BUT I can't use `for`, `while`, `goto`, `switch`, `[]`, `typedef` in all my code. So how can I replace the loop?

Comment: you can use recursion

Comment: You can also use template meta programming with variadic parameters to realize loops at compile time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It sounds like the duration of the loop needs to be determined at runtime.

Comment: @DanielH I realized that after posting my comment.

Comment: Just to add to Darlyn's comment; you may want to look specifically at "tail recursion", since this will avoid stack overflow exceptions where you don't type `stop`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693683/tail-recursion-in-c

Comment: You can use `setjmp`/`longjmp` since those are not on your list of forbidden operations.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Awwwwwwww!

Answer (score 11):

Recursion may be used. This example repeats what you enter until you type "stop" as an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void do_it()
{
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  if (s == "stop")
    return;
  std::cout << s << '\n';
  do_it();
}

int main()
{
  do_it();
  return 0;
}
```

It may not be the case here but recursion has its drawbacks. For one thing it is slower than a simple loop because in languages like C++, function call is relatively expensive. And it might cause stack overflow if it recurs too many times. Having said that, recursive version of the function can sometimes be cleaner and easier to read/understand. You can learn more about pros and cons of recursion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250733/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-recursion).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments by Jesper Juhl, they banned `goto` but forgot to ban `setjmp`/`longjmp`!

Unlike recursion-based solutions, `setjmp`/`longjmp` can't possibly cause a stack overflow if you iterate too many times.

```
#include <csetjmp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::jmp_buf jump_buffer;
    setjmp(jump_buffer);

    std::cin >> s;

    if (s == "stop")
        return 0;

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::longjmp(jump_buffer, 0);
}
```

Note that `longjmp` is potentially dangeruous, since it doesn't call destructors. Because of that it should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Challenge accepted -- C version for the original tag

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (strcmp(*argv, "stop")) {
        char *in = malloc(99);       // assume it worked
        fgets(in, 99, stdin);        // assume it worked
        *(in+strcspn(in, "\n")) = 0; // remove trailing ENTER
        main(argc + 1, &in);         // memory leak
    } else {
        printf("Stopped after %d entries.\n", argc - 1);
    }
}
```

See code running at ideone: https://ideone.com/Slx4g9

Comment: You may not call `main` yourself. `main` may not be recursive (at least not in C++)

Comment: @Ayxan: calling `main()` is allowed in C.

Comment: I think you should at least note it in the answer since the question is tagged C++